# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (1)

Tags: словообразование

Предположим, я внесу предложение о том, чтобы растение Tussilago farfara L. перестали называть "мать-и-мачеха" и стали называть "матьимачеха".

**Вопрос:** Противоречит ли указанное предложение хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?

P.S.

Чтобы не забыть: "горицвет", "держиморда", "вертихвостка", "скопидом", "сорвиголова", "перекатиполе", "вырвиглаз", ..., "гуляйполе", "неразлейвода", ... , "грабьармия", ...

Comment: А зачем?..

Comment: А что подсказывает Вам Ваша интуиция?..

Answer (score 4):

Написание мат**ьи**мачеха даёт бессмысленное сочетание *ьи*. Перед "и", нешипящие согласные в любом случае мягкие, а разделительного мягкого знака перед "и" не ставится. В принципе, не вижу ничего плохого в фонетическом написании, "матимАчеха", но в этом случае теряется этимологическая составляющая.

Если рассматривать другие подобные конструкции: казаки-разбойники, дочки-матери и др., то тут нужно понимать разницу между словом лексическим и словом фонетическим.
 1. Лексическое слово - это минимальная часть речи имеющая понятийный смысл.
 2. Фонетическое слово - это ударение и сгруппированные вокруг ударения звуки.

КазакИ-разбОйники - это одно слово лексически (выражают одно понятие), но два слова фонетических (два ударения), эту особенность и показывает дефис. Такая же картина возможна и с мать-и-мачехой, при наличии ударения и на "мать", мне попадалось произношение с двойным и с ординарным ударением, поэтому как раз название цветка - вопрос спорный.

Comment: 1. Большое спасибо.

2. Мне нужно обдумать Ваши замечания.

Comment: 1. По моему мнению, Вы умножаете сущности без крайней необходимости, вводя определение "Фонетическое слово - это ударение и сгруппированные вокруг ударения звуки".

2. На мой взгляд, ударения следует расставлять в транскрипции "лексических слов", включая слова "водопровод", "держиморда", "Новгород", "сельсовет".

3. Полностью с Вами согласен, что сочетание "ьи" бессмысленно (например, в слове "коров**ьи**"). Также бессмысленно сочетание "ск" (например, в слове "рус**ск**ий").

Comment: @Марк Из, не понял замечание касательно ударение. Как в слове "мать-и-мачеха" может быть одинарное ударение?

Comment: Думаю, "длинные" составные слова трудно произнести с одним ударением, поэтому в них отчетливо чувствуется отдельные части. Что и изображается на письме с помощью дефиса. Достаточно короткая пара со временем сливается в одно слово.  
А насчет излишних сущностей - опасный это путь! Не являемся ли мы сами вполне "излишними"?  
Скелет гораздо менее "излишен", чем живой человек. А самые гармоничные в этом смысле - паразиты (глисты, скажем). Вот уж где ничего лишнего!

Comment: @gecube, я произношу слово мать-и-мачеха примерно как [мат'эмАч'эха].

@Галактион,

1. Фонетическое слово - это факт, который понятен любому неангажированному носителю языка.
 
2. Существует много слов, пишущихся слитно, но имеющих несколько ударений *гИдроэлЕктростанция, пОлиметИлбутАнпропилЕн* и др., но читать удобнее, если слова через дефис. Из ваших примеров только сельсовет может иметь два ударения.

3. Вы произносите мать-и-мачеха как [мат'jимАч'иха]?

Comment: Я произношу слово "мать-и-мачеха" точно также, как произношу словосочетание "мать и мачеха".

По моему мнению, "матьимачеха" = "['мать'и'мачьиха]" = "мать-и-мачеха". Из чего следует, что каждое из слов "матьимачеха" и "мать-и-мачеха" имеет три ударения.

Я использую апостроф для обозначения ударения [так, как это делается в английском языке].

В заключение, ещё раз благодарю Вас за интересные замечания.

Comment: Мать-и-матика, предлагаю узаконить)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что да, т.к. название растения "мать-и-мачеха" мы можем расчленить на отдельные элементы, являющимися отдельными существующими в русском языке словами. Также можно вспомнить название игры "дочки-матери". Я вообще не могу вспомнить примеров, когда в русском языке слова склеиваются. Хочу обратить внимание, что такой тип словообразования отличается от примененного в словах "пароход", "железнодорожный" и пр.

Comment: 1. Спасибо.

2. Пожалуйста, поясните, что делают пользователи русского языка с "расчленёнными" названиями растения "мать-и-мачеха" и игры "дочки-матери"?

3. Правильно ли я Вас понял, что у пользователей русского языка нет средств для "расчленения" названия "матьимачеха"?

Comment: @Галактион,
2. Пользователи русского языка ничего не делают, а просто используют эти слова. Просто в таком написании они не просто называют некий объект, но и расшифровывают его свойства. О чем собственно и говорит @Марк Из (этимологическая составляющая).
3. Приведите примеры слов, образованных по подобию вымышленного слова "матьимачеха".

Comment: В качестве "вымышленного слова" привожу слово "иван-да-марья", которое содержит два небуквенных орфографических знака "-" и  три буквы "а".

Также буду Вам благодарен, если Вы поясните мне, как именно слова "иван", "да" и "марья" "не просто называют некий объект, но и расшифровывают его свойства".

Comment: @Галактион, не тупите! "Иван-да-марья" - не тот пример, который подтверждает Вашу точку зрения. Он как раз аналогичен слову "мать-и-мачеха" (а не слитному написанию "матьимачеха"). Касательно названий этих растений, то явно видно, что мы можем сразу сказать, что эти растения состоят из *двух* сильно различающихся частей. По этому поводу википедия пишет:

Иван-да-марья — народное название нескольких травянистых растений, цветы которых (или верхние части всего растения) отличаются присутствием двух резко различаемых окрасок, чаще всего жёлтой и синей или фиолетовой.